# Connect localhost database to web application​?

Tags: python, python-requests, webserver

I'm very new to web development in general. I have a database on localhost that will receive requests from my Heroku web app. Can I use `SimpleHTTPServer` for the case? or it has to be other modules like `ngrok` which I don't want to use because it renames its HTTP every time it restarts or is there some way to navigate the problem?

Comment: Being local, why not fetching from the remote web server or database ?

Answer (score 0):

In order for your local database to receive requests from the internet, it will need to be reachable by a public address.

One way to have a stable public address is to use a paid `ngrok` plan [which will allow you to reserve a TCP address](https://ngrok.com/pricing).

With a reserved TCP address, you can start a ngrok tunnel that will forward traffic to your local database with something like `ngrok tcp --remote-addr=<your reserved TCP address> <database port>`.